# Creating shapes program with multiple classes (different files)

Tags: beginner, objective-c, computational-geometry

I just started to learn Objective C with *Programming in Objective C* by Stephen G. Kochanand and I would love to get your feedback to see if I'm getting OOP concept with Objective-C right.

**GraphicObject.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GraphicObject : NSObject

{
    int fillColor;
    int lineColor;
    BOOL filled;
}

-(void) fillColor: (int) fc;
-(void) lineColor: (int) lc;
-(int) getFilledColor;
-(int) getLineColor;
-(BOOL) filled;

@end
```

**GraphicObject.m**

```
#import "GraphicObject.h"

@implementation GraphicObject


//--------------------------Get and Set filled/line colors----------------------------------// 

-(void) fillColor:(int)fc
{
    fillColor = fc;
}

-(void) lineColor:(int)lc
{
    lineColor = lc;
}

-(int) getFilledColor
{
    return fillColor;
}

-(int) getLineColor
{
    return lineColor;
}

//-------------------------------------Is filled?--------------------------------------------//

-(BOOL) filled
{
    filled = fillColor;
    return filled;
}

@end
```

**Rectangle.h**

```
#import "GraphicObject.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

@interface Rectangle : GraphicObject

@property float width, height, tx, ty;

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setWidth: (float) w andHeight: (float) h;
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt;
-(void) translate:(XYPoint *)point;
-(float) area;
-(float) perimeter;

@end
```

**Rectangle.m**

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation Rectangle
{
    XYPoint *origin;
}

@synthesize width, height, tx, ty;

-(void) setWidth: (float) w andHeight: (float) h
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(void) translate:(XYPoint *)point
{
    tx = origin.x + point.x;
    ty = origin.y + point.y;
}

-(void)setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt
{
    if (!origin)
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}

-(XYPoint *) origin
{
    return origin;
}

-(float) area
{
    return width * height;
}

-(float) perimeter
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}

@end
```

**XYPoint.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject

@property float x, y;

-(void) setX:(float)xP andY: (float)yP;

@end
```

**XYPoint.m**

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX:(float)xP andY:(float)yP
{
    x = xP;
    y = yP;
}

@end
```

**Circle.h**

```
#import "GraphicObject.h"

@interface Circle : GraphicObject

@property float radius, diameter;

-(float) getArea;
-(float) getCircumference;
-(void) setDiameter:(float)d andRadius: (float)r;

@end
```

**Circle.m**

```
#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle

@synthesize radius, diameter;

-(float) getArea
{
    return (radius * radius) * 3.14;
}

-(float) getCircumference
{
    return (3.14 * diameter);
}

-(void) setDiameter:(float)d andRadius: (float)r;
{
    diameter = d;
    radius = r;
}

@end
```

**Triangle.h**

```
#import "GraphicObject.h"

@interface Triangle : GraphicObject

@property float sideA, sideB, sideC, base, height;

-(float) getArea;
-(float) getPerimeter;
-(void) setBase:(float)b andHeight:(float)h;
-(void) setSideA:(float)a andB: (float)b andC: (float)c;

@end
```

**Triangle.m**

```
#import "Triangle.h"

@implementation Triangle

@synthesize sideA, sideB, sideC, base, height;

-(float) getArea
{
    return (base/2) * height;
}

-(float) getPerimeter
{
    return sideA + sideB + sideC;
}

-(void) setBase:(float)b andHeight:(float)h;
{
    base = b;
    height = h;
}

-(void) setSideA:(float)a andB: (float)b andC: (float)c
{
    sideA = a;
    sideB = b;
    sideC = c;
}

@end
```

**main**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "Circle.h"
#import "Triangle.h"
#import "GraphicObject.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

//----------------------------------Creating instance objects of all classes-------------------------------

        Rectangle *myRectangle = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
        Circle *myCircle = [[Circle alloc] init];
        Triangle *myTriangle = [[Triangle alloc] init];
        XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

//----------------------------------Testing XYPoint class and Rectangle class-------------------------------

        [myPoint setX:5 andY:10];
        [myRectangle setOrigin:myPoint];
        [myRectangle setWidth:10 andHeight:7];
        NSLog(@"Rectangle Width = %.1f Height = %.1f is at (%.1f,%.1f)", myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height, myRectangle.origin.x, myRectangle.origin.y);

//------------------------------------------Testing Circle class--------------------------------------------

        [myCircle setDiameter:6 andRadius:3];
        NSLog(@"Circle area = %.1f Circumference = %.1f", [myCircle getArea], [myCircle getCircumference]);

//-----------------------------------------Testing Triangle class-------------------------------------------

        [myTriangle setSideA:5 andB:6 andC:7];
        [myTriangle setBase:5 andHeight:12];
        NSLog(@"Triangle Perimeter = %.1f Area = %.1f", [myTriangle getPerimeter], [myTriangle getArea]);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is primarily an issue for Stack Exchange sites, and a *little* less crucial when you're looking at code in your full-screen IDE.  But, please try to avoid putting so much empty whitespace (empty lines) in your code.  It makes it harder to read with so much scrolling required.  Thanks.  Otherwise, a good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make the same suggestion as for your last question: use properties and stick to name conventions

Your code as it is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GraphicObject : NSObject

{
    int fillColor;
    int lineColor;
    BOOL filled;
}

-(void) fillColor: (int) fc;
-(void) lineColor: (int) lc;
-(int) getFilledColor;
-(int) getLineColor;
-(BOOL) filled;

@end
```

Your code with name conventions (setters of an ivar prefixed with set…, getters named as the ivar/property)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GraphicObject : NSObject

{
    int fillColor;
    int lineColor;
    BOOL filled;
}

-(void) setFillColor: (int) fc;
-(void) setLineColor: (int) lc;
-(int) filledColor;
-(int) lineColor;
-(BOOL) filled;

@end
```

Your code with properties

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GraphicObject : NSObject

{
    int fillColor;
    int lineColor;
    BOOL filled;
}
@property int fillColor;
@property int lineColor;
@property BOOL filled;

@end
```

But actually for nowadays compilers you don't need to declare iVars for properties

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GraphicObject : NSObject

@property int fillColor;
@property int lineColor;
@property BOOL filled;

@end
```

and you also dont need to declare synthesize, as it is default now

As properties generate setters7getters for you, the implementation could be

```
#import "GraphicObject.h"

@implementation GraphicObject

@end
```

---

Cocoa's name conventions suggest not to use the word `and` in method names to indicate the setting of an object's state

```
-(void) setDiameter:(float)d andRadius: (float)r;
```

becomes

```
-(void) setDiameter:(float)d radius: (float)r;
```

<sub>BTW: `diamater = radius * 2`, so there is no need to pass both</sub>

`and` is suggested for action that might be triggered after setting.
Some made up example

```
-(void) sendData:(NSData *)data 
           toURL:(NSURL *) url 
andPerformSuccessSelector:(SEL)successSelector 
   performFailureSelector:(SEL)failureSelector;

-(void) setSideA:(float)a b: (float)b c: (float)c
```

instead of XYPoint class

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX:(float)xP andY:(float)yP
{
    x = xP;
    y = yP;
}

@end
```

you could use the [CGPoint struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH2g-C016211) (iOS) or [NSPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW20) (Cocoa)

```
struct CGPoint {
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

As this is a plain C type, you cant use it, where you need to use objects. Wrap it in a NSValue object than, for example to store it into an array:

```
NSArray *points = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p1], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p2]]
```

---

I just had a look into Stephen G. Kochan's book in amazon. he is also sticking to the naming conventions, see page 96 program 6.2.

`-setNumerator:` as setter, `-numerator` as getter.

Although he is not using properties in this example, he most likely will also explain and use them later in the book.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great feedback again! I stick to name conventions next time :) Regarding the struct yes, I read about it a bit but he still didnt go over this in the book, I know he will later on (Just got to page 9). Thanks again, we need more people like you here and this site will be even more awesome ;) @vikingosegundo

Comment: Just to emphasize again: naming conventions are very important, as different parts of the cocoa framework depend on them.

Comment: Thanks! and I meant chapter 9 (not page:/) @vikingosegundo