# Creating a Playlist program

Tags: objective-c

Exercise:

> Define three new classes, called **Song**, **Playlist**, and
>   **MusicCollection**. A Song   object will contain information about a particular song, such as its title,   artist, album, and playing time.
>   A Playlist object will contain the name of   the playlist and a
>   collection of songs. A MusicCollection object will contain   a
>   collection of playlists, including a special master playlist called
>   library   that contains every song in the collection. Define these
>   three classes and   write methods to do the following:
>
> - Create a Song object and set its information.
> - Create a Playlist object, and add songs to and remove songs from a playlist.   A new song should be added to the master playlist if it’s
>     not already   there. Make sure that if a song is removed from the
>     master playlist, it's   removed from all playlists in the music
>     collection as well.
> - Create a MusicCollection object, and add playlists to and remove playlists   from the collection.
>
> Search and display the information about any song, any playlist, or
>   the   entire music collection.    Make sure all your classes do not
>   leak memory!

This is my code:

**Song.h**

```
@interface Song : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist, *title, *album, *time;

-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andPlayingTime:(NSString *)theTime;

@end
```

**Song.m**

```
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Song

@synthesize title, album, artist, time;

-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andPlayingTime:(NSString *)theTime{

    self.title = theSongName;
    self.artist = theArtist;
    self.album = theAlbum;
    self.time = theTime;
}

@end
```

**Playlist.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"

@interface PlayList : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *playListName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *songsCollection;


-(void) addSongToPlayList:(Song *) someSong;
-(void) removeSongFromPlayList:(Song *) theSong;
-(void) print;
-(id) initWithName:(NSString *) listName;
-(id) init;

@end
```

**Playlist.m**

```
#import "PlayList.h"
#import "Song.h"

@implementation PlayList

@synthesize songsCollection, playListName;

-(void) addSongToPlayList:(Song *) someSong{

    [songsCollection addObject:someSong];
}

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)listName{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.playListName = listName;
        songsCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) init {

    return [self initWithName:@"No Name"];
}

-(void) removeSongFromPlayList:(Song *)theSong{

    [songsCollection removeObjectIdenticalTo:theSong];

}

-(void) print{

    NSLog(@"------------------- %@ -------------------------------------",playListName);

    for (Song *mySong in songsCollection) {

        NSLog(@"%-15s %-25s %-18s %-10s",[mySong.artist UTF8String], [mySong.title UTF8String], [mySong.album UTF8String], [mySong.time UTF8String]);


    }
    NSLog(@"-----------------------------------------------------------------");
}


@end
```

**MusicCollection.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PlayList.h"

@interface MusicCollection : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *playlistsCollection;
@property (nonatomic, copy) PlayList *library;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *) collectionName;

//-(void) addSongToPlaylist:(Song *) aSong toPlaylist:(PlayList *) playlistName;
//-(void) removeSongFromPlaylist:(Song *) aSong fromPlaylist:(PlayList *) playlistName;
-(void) addPlaylistToCollection:(PlayList *) playListToAdd;
-(void) removePlayListFromCollection:(PlayList *) playListToRemove;
-(void) searchCollection:(NSString *) someCollection;
-(void) list;

@end
```

**MusicCollection.m**

```
#import "MusicCollection.h"

@implementation MusicCollection

@synthesize playlistsCollection, library, name;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)collectionName {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {


        name = [NSString stringWithString:collectionName];
        playlistsCollection = [NSMutableArray array];
        library = [[PlayList alloc] initWithName:@"Library"];

}

    return self;
}

-(void) addPlaylistToCollection:(PlayList *)playListToAdd{

    if ([playlistsCollection containsObject: playListToAdd] == NO)
        [playlistsCollection addObject: playListToAdd];


    for (Song *song in playListToAdd.songsCollection) {

    if ([library.songsCollection containsObject:song] == NO)

        [library addSongToPlayList:song];

    }

}


-(void) removePlayListFromCollection:(PlayList *)playListToRemove {

    if ([playlistsCollection containsObject: playListToRemove] == YES)
        [playlistsCollection removeObject:playListToRemove];

    for (Song *song in playListToRemove.songsCollection)
        [library removeSongFromPlayList:song];
}

-(void) list {

    for (PlayList *playlist in playlistsCollection)
        [playlist print];
}

-(void) searchCollection:(NSString *)someCollection {

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (PlayList *lookUp in playlistsCollection) {
        if ([lookUp.playListName rangeOfString:someCollection options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [results addObject:lookUp];
    }

   for (PlayList *playlists in results) {

       [playlists print];

   }


}


@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"
#import "Playlist.h"
#import "MusicCollection.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Song *song1 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song2 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song3 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song4 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song5 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song6 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *song7 = [[Song alloc] init];


        [song1 setSong:@"Heart Attack" andArtist:@"Demi Lovato" andAlbum:@"Demi's Album" andPlayingTime:@"3:15"];
        [song2 setSong:@"When I Was Your Man" andArtist:@"Bruno Mars" andAlbum:@"Bruno Album" andPlayingTime:@"1:31"];
        [song3 setSong:@"Harlem Shake" andArtist:@"Baauer" andAlbum:@"Baauer Album" andPlayingTime:@"3:22"];
        [song4 setSong:@"I believe I Can Fly" andArtist:@"R-Kelly" andAlbum:@"R-Kelly Album" andPlayingTime:@"2:33"];
        [song5 setSong:@"A Milli" andArtist:@"Lil Wayne" andAlbum:@"Lil Wayne Album" andPlayingTime:@"1:34"];
        [song6 setSong:@"Diamonds" andArtist:@"Rihana" andAlbum:@"Rihana Album" andPlayingTime:@"2:32"];
        [song7 setSong:@"Work Hard Play Hard" andArtist:@"Wiz Khalifa" andAlbum:@"Wiz Khalifa Album" andPlayingTime:@"1:54"];


        PlayList *playlist1 = [[PlayList alloc] initWithName:@"My Favorit's"];
        PlayList *playlist2 = [[PlayList alloc] initWithName:@"Good Time's"];
        PlayList *playlist3 = [[PlayList alloc] initWithName:@"Partying"];
        PlayList *playlist4 = [[PlayList alloc] initWithName:@"Hip Hop"];

        [playlist1 addSongToPlayList:song1];
        [playlist1 addSongToPlayList:song2];
        [playlist2 addSongToPlayList:song3];
        [playlist2 addSongToPlayList:song4];
        [playlist3 addSongToPlayList:song5];
        [playlist3 addSongToPlayList:song7];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song7];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song6];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song5];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song4];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song3];
        [playlist4 addSongToPlayList:song2];


        MusicCollection *myCollection = [[MusicCollection alloc] initWithName:@"music"];

        [myCollection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist1];
        [myCollection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist2];
        [myCollection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist3];
        [myCollection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist4];


        [myCollection list];

        [myCollection searchCollection:@"Hip Hop"];

        [playlist1 removeSongFromPlayList: song2];

        [myCollection removePlayListFromCollection:playlist2];

        [myCollection list];

        [myCollection.library print];


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this code decent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already wrote on [another of your questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/creating-shapes-program-with-multiple-classes-different-files-in-objective-c):

```
-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andPlayingTime:(NSString *)theTime;
```

This violates the naming conventions. it should be named

```
-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName artist:(NSString *)theArtist album:(NSString *)theAlbum playingTime:(NSString *)theTime;
```

If you dont believe me, [trust apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH)

> Don’t use “and” to link keywords that are attributes of the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *) name types:(NSArray *)fileTypes;
> ```
>
> Right.
>
> ```
> - (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path andFile:(NSString *)name andTypes:(NSArray *)fileTypes;
> ```
>
> Wrong.

`and…` indicates a second distinct action

> If the method describes two separate actions, use “and” to link them.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)openFile:(NSString *)fullPath withApplication:(NSString *)appName andDeactivate:(BOOL)flag;
> ```

---

```
-(void) list {

    for (PlayList *playlist in playlistsCollection)
        [playlist print];
}
```

`list` is a quite unintuitive name. `printPlayListCollection` or similar would be better.

---

you should add a `init…` method to `Song` that take all important information. The idea behind this is that by using tis as designated initializer you ensure that your song objects will always be in a valid state. Let's assume you also write the sound playing functionality: with `[[Song alloc] init]` you would create a object that has nothing for playback. before you would play it, each time you must assure it is playable.
But if you would raise an exception if the plain `init` and create `initWithArtistName:songName:…filePath:…` as designated initializer you can be quite sure, everything is set up correctly once you try to play it.

---

`@sythesize` statements arent necessary anymore. It will be implicit added.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist;
```

will result in an implicit synthesize statement equivalent to

```
@synthesize artist = _artist;
```

Comment: Thank you buddy. I know this `and` is annoying, it's just that the author in the book use it all the time so i just got use to it, but i will get out of it. i definitely see that its not acceptable, and would make more sense to use it if there if a different action to preform in the method. @vikingosegundo

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: "Programming in Objective C" by stephen Kochan @vikingosegundo